# How to set a unique id to dynamically generated views in Kotlin for Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have button that when pressed creates the following layout:

```
fun handleAddTally(view: View) {
    with(view as Button) {
        btn_count += 1

        val this_btn = view.resources.getResourceEntryName(id)
        var container_overall = LinearLayout(this@SecondActivity)
        container_overall.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL)

        var container_inputs= LinearLayout(this@SecondActivity)
        container_inputs.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL)
        var text_width= TextView(this@SecondActivity)
        text_width.setText("W:")
        var input_width= EditText(this@SecondActivity)
        text_width.setWidth(30)
        input_width.setWidth(90)
        input_width.id = width_count+btn_count
            }
}
```

I want to be able to generate multiple layouts like that of above but with each instances having a unique id. Would that be possible? If it is not, I would really appreciate a way to assign a unique identifier of any sort to each instances of the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate unique id dynamically for your views using `View.generateViewId()` function.

For you programmatically created layout or view, you can set id like this

```
container_overall.id = View.generateViewId()
```

Comment: Is there any way I could add the id myself rather than have it be generated?

Comment: Yes, you can just assign any integer to the view, view's setId() function takes an integer as an Id. But this way you have to make sure that every id is unique. Using `View.generateViewId()` makes sure that each generated Ids are unique.

Comment: Why do you want to create ids yourself instead of using `View.generateViewId()` function?

Comment: I am using the id as a way to modify the text of a TextView element that is generated together with the inputText.

I did managed to solve the problem with another solution but your help is really appreciated! :) I will mark your answer as correct